# SudzC issue with SOAP keywords

Tags: iphone, ios, soap, sudzc

I have this response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:SurfaceElementListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://isiows.isiom.fr/schema/DmdCreation" xmlns:ns3="http://isiows.isiom.fr/schema/Error" xmlns:ns4="http://isiows.isiom.fr/schema/DmdDetail">
         <SurfaceElementListResult>
            <idSurfaceElement>9482</idSurfaceElement>
            <name>R04-</name>
            <type>NIVEAU</type>
         </SurfaceElementListResult>
         <SurfaceElementListResult>
            <idSurfaceElement>9486</idSurfaceElement>
            <name>Zone A</name>
            <type>ZONE</type>
         </SurfaceElementListResult>
      </ns2:SurfaceElementListResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am waiting each object to be deserialized to NSDictionary, as it works on all the other WS response except one above.
In comparison with other responses, in SOAP.m:`+ (id) deserialize: (CXMLNode*) element` method, all the responses for the statement `NSString* type = [Soap getNodeValue:element withName:@"type"];` return nil, so it is continues with return `[Soap deserializeAsDictionary:element];` and I get the necessary result.
In my case when I reach to `NSString* type = [Soap getNodeValue:element withName:@"type"];` the statement returns "NIVEAU" for the first object and "ZONE" for the other object, which does not allow the application go and execute `[Soap deserializeAsDictionary:element];` and I get a string object instead of NSDictionary as parse result.

Could you please help me solving this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get formatted string"? The issue or problem is not very clear, could you please rephrase it? and Which does not allow application do and execute part not clear too! What you want the code to do ultimately?

Comment: I want to get a workaround for the case, when my soap response has as a field name <type></type>, which is a SOAP keyword.

Comment: is WSDL is made by you or do you have any control over it? I had similar issue and we end adding namespace to "similar named element" [See : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp ]

Comment: I tried changing the field name in the WSDL for to <type2> and even though I received <type>, I don't know if it is correct anyway. And yes I don't have any other control over it.

Comment: Well Normally the response from server should have prefix while working with web services like this. I know your problem now, I am just trying to work out safe solution. How many different types you can get? by type I mean the value of it, like NIVEAU/ZONE...is it a lot?

Comment: please test my answer. Hope it will do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
// Deserialize an object as a generic object
+ (id) deserialize: (CXMLNode*) element{

    // Get the type
    NSString* type = [Soap getNodeValue:element withName:@"type"];
```

looking into the [Soap getNodeValue]... I figured out, that the use of this function is rather too general. It is used as for getting the attributes of the field, as the values of the fields.

```
// Gets the value of a named node from a parent node.

+ (NSString*) getNodeValue: (CXMLNode*) node withName: (NSString*) name {

    // Set up the variables
    if(node == nil || name == nil) { return nil; }
    CXMLNode* child = nil;

    // If it's an attribute get it
    if([node isKindOfClass: [CXMLElement class]])
    {
        child = [(CXMLElement*)node attributeForName: name];
        if(child != nil) {
            return [child stringValue];
        }
    }

    // Otherwise get the first element
    child = [Soap getNode: node withName: name];
    if(child != nil) {
        return [child stringValue];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

In this care I created a new method which is getting only the attribute value:

```
// Gets the value of a node attribute
+ (NSString*) getNodeAttributeValue: (CXMLNode*) node withName: (NSString*) name{
    // Set up the variables
    if(node == nil || name == nil) { return nil; }
    CXMLNode* child = nil;

    // If it's an attribute get it
    if([node isKindOfClass: [CXMLElement class]])
    {
        child = [(CXMLElement*)node attributeForName: name];
        if(child != nil) {
            return [child stringValue];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

and replaced it in Soap:deserialize:

```
// Deserialize an object as a generic object
+ (id) deserialize: (CXMLNode*) element{

    // Get the type
    NSString* type = [Soap getNodeAttributeValue:element withName:@"type"];
//  NSString* type = [Soap getNodeValue:element withName:@"type"];
    if(type == nil || type.length == 0) {
```

And it works perfectly for me, till now. Hope it will help others with the same situation.